# Login SSO: get claims from msal azure authentication response

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal, flask-login, claims

We have to develop a integration to a external login provided by Azure AD (SAML 2.0).
Our system uses react for the front-end and python for the backend. The login workflow should works like this:

Front-end Login Page --> Azure - Success Login --> Azure requests to our backend success URL with user info

Everything is working fine and after a success login the Azure request arrives to our backend server. The problem is the way to read that requests and how to extract the basic information (user, email....).

We don't see any info in body or headers, only some encoded params in the url. The requests received is like this:

`https://<MY_DOMAIN>#code=<RARE_CODE>&state=<BASE64_ENCODE_JSON>&session_state=<UUID_CODE>`

The information of the logged user (claims) is supposed to be there, in any of those params, probably encoded in the "code" parameter. I think there must be a way to decode that information but I can't find answers in any documentation.

Any in-house solution to be able to recover those claims and access the user's login data?